# How to make 10 as TEN using oracle sql

Tags: oracle

How to make 10 as TEN using Oracle Sql?
eg: 20 as TWENTY
    1000 as THOUSAND

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this in the application and not the database?

Answer (score 5):

```
select your_col, (to_char(to_date(your_cold,'j'), 'jsp')) from your_table;
```

should [do the trick](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123). It has limitations on the size of the number though, with a workaround [provided here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650) that is a bit more involved - the idea is to split your number by groups of three digits, convert those with the above trick and add the proper "quantifier" (*thousand*, *million*, *billion*, etc.).